# Amazon Redshift query and case sensitivity

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I want to assign case-sensitive alias to column names in query, but PostgreSQL just ignores any case in alias and leaves it lowercase. I know that it stores everything in lowercase, but I just want case sensitive alias in query. Any way to get it working? Renaming stuff manually after query execution for huge dict sets sounds ridiculous.

**Update**: Important note - I'm using Amazon Redshift. Is it possible that Amazon limits it?

Example

```
select superid from supertable;  
...  
cursor.execute(query)  
results = cursor.fetchall()    
for row in results:
  print row['superid']  
// ^ WORKING

------------------------

select superid as "superId" from supertable;
...

cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
  print row['superId']
// ^ NOT WORKING
```

Comment: I can't replicate it. Using `col_name as FOO` (no quotes) de-capitalizes `FOO`, but `col_name as "FOO"` (with quotes) doesn't seem to.

Comment: Use double quotes around labels if you want them to be case sensitive.

Comment: If I use single quotes in query then I receive error in query, if I use double quotes in getitem, then it throws same error. I tried to check keys of resulting list and they are all lowercase independent of case in query. Maybe it's redshift Amazon limitation, I added note about that. Still looking for help.

Comment: Redshift doesn't support that as for now. /shrug

Comment: [retagged]. BTW: the general advice is not to rely on case-senesitivity. (until now, I never realised this could be applied to aliases as well )

Comment: This: `select superid as "superId" from supertable;` is correct. So if that isn't working then whatever is wrong here is specific to Redshift.

Comment: I just found [this link (click)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=523569) on Amazon forums. It's actual Redshift's limitation and there's no fix available.

Comment: Fix: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_case_sensitive_identifier.html

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a Redshift thing.  It is very finicky about using mixed-case.  While a SELECT statement using mixed case will work fine using the JDBC connector, it will ignore your attempts to use mixed case via SQL internals and perhaps the API, which is what I think psycopg uses.

I ran into a problem where I couldn't load data using the COPY command because I was unable to create column names with any upper case characters.  COPY works fine from one redshift table to another, regardless of case, but COPY from S3 does not.

I tried double quotes around column names, but Redshift ignored them, while my local postgres instance worked just fine and used my literal quoted strings with mixed case.

For reference, my question (and answer) are here.

[Does case matter when 'auto' loading data from S3 into a Redshift table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367514/does-case-matter-when-auto-loading-data-from-s3-into-a-redshift-table)

Hope that helps, even if it's not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: Oh man, I run into this recently. It took my 4 days to figure it out. Commenting in case some other poor soul goes through that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Another question in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128095/loading-json-data-to-aws-redshift-results-in-null-values/58411291#58411291

Comment: Follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_case_sensitive_identifier.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to try, it may be about localization. Try with different table or column names which does not contains "I". not superId may be just super.