# How to keep the upper case and lower case letters in a column alias in the results in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift we are trying to give more meaningful aliases to the columns we are returning from the queries as we are importing the results into TABLEAU, the issue is that RedShift turns all the letter to lower case ones, i.e. from "Event Date" it then returns "event date", any idea on how to work this one out to keep the alias given?

[image: Query]

[image: Final Column Name]

Comment: This is possibly being caused by the SQL Client you are using. Can you try using a different client or use `psql` to see it come back in raw form?

Comment: you can rename in Tableau itself if you're able to do it manually?

Comment: One of the solutions is to use jsonpath, see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411291/7127824)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but for anyone else looking, you can enable case sensitivity, so if you want to return a column with camel casing for example

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;
```

Then in your query wrap what you want to return the column as in double quotes

```
SELECT column AS "thisName"
```

Or as per OP's example

```
SELECT a.event_date AS "Event Date"
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_case_sensitive_identifier.html

Edit: To have this behaviour as default for the cluster you will need to create/update a parameter group in Configurations => Workload Management.  You can't change the settings for the default parameter group.  Note, you will need to reboot the cluster after applying the parameter group for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this in Redshift. all columns are lowercase only.

You can enforce upper case only by using

```
set describe_field_name_in_uppercase to on;
```

Also see the examples here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html you can see that the upper case characters are returned as lower case. and it says "identifiers are case-insensitive and are folded to lowercase in the database"

You can of course rename the column to include uppercase within Tableau.

Answer (score -1):

I was going through AWS docs for redshift and looks like **INTCAP** function can solve your use case

For reference => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INITCAP.html

**Brief description (copied)**

The INITCAP function makes the first letter of each word in a string uppercase, and any subsequent letters are made (or left) lowercase. Therefore, it is important to understand which characters (other than space characters) function as word separators. A word separator character is any non-alphanumeric character, including punctuation marks, symbols, and control characters. All of the following characters are word separators:

! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~

And in your case you have declared field name as event_date which will convert to Event_Date.

And next you can use **REPLACE** function to replace underscore '_'

For reference => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REPLACE.html

Comment: Thanks @Bhavesh, this is useful indeed for the results of a column, the issue is that I need the title of the column to have Upper Case letters, any ideas on that?

Answer (score -2):

You need to put

```
set describe_field_name_in_uppercase to on;
```

in your Tableau's Initial SQL.

Comment: This doesn't actually work, it sets the column names to only capitals, so in the case of OP's example: `"EVENT DATE"`