Rename Excel columns in VBA
How can I rename a column after I add the data to the Excel sheet? I tried implementing the solution in Rename an Excel table column using VBA , but wasn't sure how to implement ListObjects.
I also tried implementing the following, but I'm not sure how to add it when it's stand-alone and not part of a string (as it's done when the macro records it): Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{""emp_id"",""Employee ID""}})
Sub GetEmployees()
     
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "select emp_id, emp_name from Employee " & _
        "where emp_date between '" & Range("C3").Value & "' and '" & Range("C4").Value & "'" & _
        "order by emp_date asc"
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      
    Sheets("Data").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("redshiftdb").ODBCConnection
        .CommandText = sql
    End With
    
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'This renames the columns, but for just a split second. Then it goes back to the old name
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A5").Value = "Employee Id"
    Worksheets("Data").Range("B5").Value = "Employee Name"

    'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").ListColumns("emp_id").Name = "Employee ID"
    'Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{""emp_id"",""Employee ID""}
End Sub


Might be easier to do that in your SQL: sql = "select emp_id as ""Employee Id"", emp_name as ""Employee Name"" from Employee " & _

I'm using redshift, so aliases with uppercase don't work.

This doesn't work?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810933/478884

...though I'm not sure how you'd use that in this context.  Have you tried setting up your query in Power Query? - you may be able to combine the query and the renaming in that context.
